# Making a deterministic graph

Tags: jgraphx

Is it possible to make the graph deterministic? I mean e.g.:

if I add A vertex and then B, the graph will look the same as if I would add B first and then A.

I am currently using a mxCompactTreeLayout, but it doesn't work as I'd like to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely, however you will need to create the rules yourself, since they are probably very specific to your use case. I call this logic inside from the `mxGraphComponent.ImportCell` by inheriting from mxGraphComponent and overriding the `ImportCell`-method to inject relations and reorganize the graph if/when necessary.

```
@Override
public Object[] importCells(Object[] cells, double dx, double dy, Object target, Point location) {
    Object[] importedCells = super.importCells(cells, dx, dy, target, location);

    for (Object cell : importedCells) {
        updateGraphRelationsFor(cell);
    }

    return importedCells;
}
```

Note that I call the `updateGraphRelationsFor()` with the `importedCells` returned from the `super.importCells` method because they will be cloned inside of this method.